# Fire workflow based on the record owner's timezone

Tags: workflow, timezone

We use Salesforce to facilitate job postings and hiring new volunteers. We have a workflow that removes job postings from our website on the posting end date, which is a date field on our job posting object. Our instance's default timezone is EST, but we have job postings on the west coast and we're noticing that job postings are being pulled from the website at 9PM PST instead of at midnight, like they are in EST.

We want all job postings to deactivate at midnight, regardless of timezone. Is it possible to fire a workflow based on the record owner's timezone (the owner of the job posting), instead of basing it on our environment's timezone? Or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workflow will fire based upon the Locale settings of your Default Workflow User. If you have a field on your object to identify whether a job posting is on the West Coast you can use it as a filter in your WFR.

Add IsWestCoast = FALSE to your existing WFR.
Create a second WFR with the same details but with IsWestCoast = TRUE. In this WFR you need to adjust the time that it fires to 3AM EST.